# Checksum for multipage tiff document

Tags: tiff, checksum

I want to calculate the checksum for a large tiff file that might not fit in memory. Will I get a reliable value if I instead calculate the checksum of every page and then calculate the checksum of the array of page checksums or will I run into a mathematical problem that I am not seeing and the only correct way to do it is to in fact work with the whole thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if understood the question correctly, but with most checksum algorithms you only have to load a [small part of the message to memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode). Because of that operating on the streams instead of memory locations is possible and has been done [before](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/crypto/MD5Stream.as?spec=svn61&r=61).

**Edit**:

I only know that you have to be careful with Adler-32 when checksumming short messages, you would not be covering the whole hash space and false positives are more likely (yest, the array of checksums would probably be a short message).

With crypto hashes I honestly don't know. My intuition is that md5(msg1 + msg2 + ...) is as reliable as md5(md5(msg1) + md5(msg2) + ...) but we'll have to wait for someone smarter than me to give definitive answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the link - but how far off would I be if I calculate the chechsum of the page checksums, instead of the checksum of the whole multipage document?